# Why different CPU count from nproc and nproc --all in OpenVZ container?

Tags: cpu, openvz

I'm trying `nproc` and `nproc --all` in an OpenVZ container to count the number of CPU threads assigned to the vps by upstream provider. While `nproc` resulting 1, `nproc --all` resulting 24 CPU threads. May anyone please help me in explaining this?

The upstream provider is supposed to assign only one CPU and `cat /proc/cpuinfo` is also saying that. Then from where and how this 24 is coming?

Please find a screenshot here https://prnt.sc/hfzeuw. I'm using `CentOS 7` inside the vps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using a 12 core proc with hyperthreading, most likely.  They have assigned one of these threads to your container.

From the man page:

```
   nproc - print the number of processing units available

   nproc [OPTION]...

   --all  print the number of installed processors`
```

EDIT:

What happens when you type the following:

`[user@host]$ getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`

?

Comment: `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` returning to 1

Comment: As anticipated it is showing the one (1) you have avail. 

Are you familiar with containers? If you'd like to learn more, I suggest reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVZ

Comment: More than happy! :) Good luck!